# How to prevent abuse of unsubcription from a newsletter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, subscription

Preface: I'm not a web developer, I'm just trying to learn as I go while making my first website.

I stumbled on an engineering problem in regards to unsubscribing from newsletter.
I thought it would be a good idea to use a get method with a parameter like this:

```
/unsubscribe=qwerty@qwerty.com
```

Then I went ahead and implemented it in javascript:

```js
app.get('/unsubscribe:subEmail', async (req, res) => {
    subEmail = req.params.subEmail.substring(1);
    let subscriber = await Subscriber.findOne({ email: subEmail })
    if(subscriber == null){
        res.send('subscriber doesnt exist')
        return;
    }
    await subscriber.delete()
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

But, then it occurred to me; how do I make sure the email provided *does not* belong to another subscriber?

Question: What are the good engineering solutions used to prevent abusing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of traditional options.

## Secrets

Unsubscribe users based on a secret and not an email address.

Traditionally, this is a GUID including in a link to the unsubscribe endpoint that is included in each email sent out.

## Authentication

Require users to login to their account before providing access to the feature.

This is typically provided as a second option since the link in the email has less friction.

Comment: In regards to Secrets part of your answer; do I generate that GUID when subscription occurs? And save it to database along with the email?

Comment: That seems like a reasonable time to do so. Yes.

Comment: I implemented default: uuid.v4 and used the value of that instead of email in the get method. And it works well, thank you.